# Upload CSV / Text Files From Blob To SharePoint using Azure Data Factory

Tags: sharepoint, azure-data-factory

What are the ways to copy files (text/CSV etc) from Blob to Sharepoint using azure data factory ?

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe Data Factory supports writing to Sharepoint, but [Azure Logic Apps does](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/connectors/connectors-create-api-sharepoint#:%7E:text=Connect%20to%20SharePoint%201%20Sign%20in%20to%20the,the%20necessary%20connection%20information.%20...%20More%20items...%20). You could execute a Logic App (with an HTTP trigger) from Data Factory using a Web activity.